# How to force quit an app that doesn't show in the Force Quit Applications menu?

Tags: force-quit

I have an app running that is showing in my statusbar icon menu, but it's *rainbowing* - I can't click on it or interact with it in any way.

The same application doesn't show in my Force Quit Applications menu.

What choices do I have?

Comment: Activity monitor. `kill` in terminal too. see questions in the sidebar

Comment: But don't shoot at random, avoid your face and feet.

Answer (score 4):

The Force Quit menu will only show foreground windowed applications, not all processes.  Launch Activity Monitor, and search for the name of the app, or look for processes marked in Red with "Not Responding". There is a Quit button in the toolbar, where you can choose to Force Quit a process.

Items in the menubar are sometimes controlled by the `SystemUIServer` process, which may also need to be restarted.